# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - custom class

Tags: ios

I have created a very simple custom class, just a model really, to hold some data about NSURLConnections so I can keep track of them. The purpose being to have an array of them, an array of ConnectionInfo objects.

```
@interface ConnectionInfo : NSObject

@property NSString *connectionDescription;
@property int *campaignID;
@property int *requestType; //0 - Score, 1 - Image

@end
```

I haven't bothered putting it into it's own file as it's so simple, so it just sits at the top of my view controller.

Anyway, Xcode doesn't give me any issues with that, however, once I want to create an instance of this class by

```
ConnectionInfo *thisConnection = [[ConnectionInfo alloc] init];
```

it throws 2 of the errors below:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ConnectionInfo", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in ServerTestViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Everything I have looked at around Stackoverflow is about people having issues with imported libraries but this is my own custom class.

Comment: Does there exist any implemenation of `ConnectionInfo`?

Comment: A header ain't an implementation, it's just for making the **compiler** happy (not the linker, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the implementation for the class, create one as follows

```
@implementation ConnectionInfo
@end
```

**Why is this needed?**

All you had done previously is declare the class interface. All this does is inform the user of the class (and the compiler) what to expect within the implementation. It does not declare how the class works. Without an implementation, you don't have a class to use!

**Why is the implementation empty?**

You may think putting a blank implementation in is pointless. What this will do is inform the compiler how to create an object. Whilst your implementation does nothing, you inherit from `NSObject`, which has a lot to do with object creation. Also, with the latest Xcode, you don't need to manually `@synthesize` your properties, so these are also set up for you automatically when you declare your `@implementation`.

Comment: This is not fixing my problem when the implementation is from a Cocoapods managed source